# Singleton pattern usage for sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, singleton

There is lot of stuff available on the internet on how to use singleton pattern for sqlite in android, my question is why use singleton pattern to communicate with sqlite database

Comment: Consider, what are the risks when there are more than one sqlite database. What are the risks of leaking?

Answer (score 1):

Using a singleton class to manage access to your database can help developers avoid the mistake of leaking database instances (i.e. opening but not closing database instances).

This approach, and the problem is solves, is described nicely in this post: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html.